Identify a 14-pin IC in Pro'sKit MT-7051 cable tester
I'm trying to repair a Pro'sKit MT-7051 multi-modular cable tester, which works with RJ45 TIA568A/B, 10 Base-T, Token ring, RJ-11/RJ-12 USOC, and coaxial BNC cables. The main integrated circuit (IC) in the device is damaged, and I need to identify it to find a replacement.
Here are the details I know about the IC:

It has 14 pins.
Pin 3 is connected to an LED.
Pin 4 is for power (VCC).
Pin 7 is connected to ground (GND).

The IC has no readable markings, so I can’t determine the exact model. Has anyone worked with this device or knows which IC might be used in it?
The master part


The remote part


Connection example


Do you know how the device is normally supposed to work and/or be connected?

please provide details about the other half of the device

Hi @vir the MT-7051N cable tester is used to test continuity and wiring configurations for RJ45, RJ11, and coaxial cables. You connect the end of the cable to the 'Master' unit's port and the other end to the 'Remote' unit's port. Turn on the tester, and it will verify the cable's continuity and identify any wiring issues or breaks in the line.

Sure @jsotola , I just updated the post to include details about the other half of the device.

It’s unlikely, @Burglups. The IC in the tester seems more like a 4017 decade counter. It has its own clock (CLK) and reset, with a pinout matching typical 4017 behavior (e.g., LED on pin 3, VCC on pin 4, GND on pin 7). This IC is more commonly used for sequencing than in string lights.

Maybe a low-end microcontroller with proprietary firmware. In which case you're out of luck.
